# Borrar espacios en blanco de un String

Tags: java, string

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función de Java que me permita borrar los espacios en blanco entre dos palabras de un String. Se que existe la opción de utilizar trip() p trim() para eliminar los espacios en blanco de los extremos. Pero quisira saber si existe algo para borrar los espacios en blanco entre dos palabras dada una cadena de String.

Por ejemplo dado un nombre:

`String nombre = "Catarina    rafaela";`

Que salga:

`Catarina rafaela`

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: `replaceAll` con regex (expresiones regulares) deberia funcionarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dice [masterguru](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/263200/masterguru), usando expresiones regulares y replaceall debería valerte:

```
//---- | \\s{2,} busca dos o más espacios. | ----
nombre.replaceAll("\\s{2,}"," ");
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Me sirvió! Muchas gracias a ambos @ptfdeveloper